# Accessing a directory on a web server that has restricted access from an external Web site

Tags: php, asp.net, web-config

I am working on a Wordpress page rendered with a template. There is a link on the page to a another webpage on an external site (i.e., it is on another domain altogether) and thios page requires a login. Access to the directory that contains that page is controlled by a Web config and works only on successful login. The web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
     <appSettings/>
     <connectionStrings/>
     <system.web>
     <authorization>
         <allow roles="Administrator, Client"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
     </authorization>
     </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How do I modify this or make any other changes in the external site so that the link on my wordpress page successfully manages to access the external site and I get to see the page without having to login(like make an exception for a request from my wordpress site or something along those lines.) I want to do this because the same user would have already logged in to my wordpress site and would necessarily have to login at this external site again just in order to view the external page. Is this doable?

P.S: The external Web site I have mentioned about is a ASP.NET based web site.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Location element in your web.config and add the authorization element for that specific location. This way you can control access to specific locations.